# How to get php row values?

Tags: php, html

management.php is the code which get information in php by a table.
And managementdel.php is the code which del the information.
I use mysql_fetch_array to show all data,and beside every information have a herf to delete 
echo data in database.

When I del ,there no error inside.but database information haven't delete.

management.php

```
 $con1 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

      mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

      $sql1 = "Select LoginID , Password , Permission
              from loginacc where Permission = 2 ";


      $results = mysql_query($sql1,$con1);

       echo "<tr><th>會員帳號</th></tr>";

      echo "<table border=5 cellpadding=10>";

      echo "<tr><th></th><th>帳號</th><th>密碼</th><th>權限</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 

       echo "<tr><td>
        <a href='searchtable.php?lid=$row[0]'>get information</a></td><td>$row[0]</td><td><input type=text id='row1' name='row1' value='$row[1]' /></td>
                  <td>$row[2]</td><td>
                  <a href='searchtable.php?lid=$row[0]'>Change</a></td><td>
                  <a href='managementdel.php?lid=$row[0]'>Delete</a></td></tr>";

      }

      echo "</table>";
```

managementdel.php

```
<?php

$ac = $_GET['rowname'];

 $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

  mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

  $sql = "delete from loginacc where LoginID = '$ac'";   




  if(mysql_query($sql))

  {
               echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=management.php>';

        }
        else
        {
                echo 'fail!';
                echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=management.php>';
        }


echo mysql_error()
?>
```

Comment: why $_GET['rowname'] when it seems you sent lid?

Comment: and printing user passwords in table!?

Comment: It seems that there are some issues with your echoing lol. Did you forget to concatenate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is so much stuff wrong with your script, I won't address it all. What I will do is answer your question that you asked which is:** "Why it won't delete from database."

What is wrong in your script:

- Using depreciated `mysql_*` library (*See notes below*)
- Using `meta refresh` to redirect instead of something like `header('Location: link');`
- Not sanitizing user input -> `$_GET['lid']`.
- Posting user password in the table. (*Hopefully not being stored as plaintext*)

---

As stated, you're trying to get:

```
$_GET['rowname']
```

When you are sending `lid` -> `managementdel.php?lid=$row[0]`. You have to change that to:

```
$ac = $_GET['lid'];
```

---

### NOTES

Please stay away from `mysql_*` functions as the library is depreciated.

Use either of the following **two** instead:

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- [Mysqli Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

And if you aren't going to do that, atleast try and sanitize your user inputs to prevent SQL Injections.

Using functions like [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) will help you but won't be as comprehensive as PDO/mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

in managementdel.php file instead of

```
$ac = $_GET['rowname'];
```

there should be

```
$ac = $_GET['lid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**management.php**

```
<?php
 $con1 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

      mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

      $sql1 = "Select LoginID , Password , Permission
              from loginacc where Permission = 2 ";


      $results = mysql_query($sql1,$con1);

       echo "<tr><th>會員帳號</th></tr>";

      echo "<table border=5 cellpadding=10>";

      echo "<tr><th></th><th>帳號</th><th>密碼</th><th>權限</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 

       echo "<tr><td>
        <a href='searchtable.php?lid= " . $row[0] . "'>get information</a></td><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td><input type=text id='row1' name='row1' value='" . $row[1] . "' /></td>
                  <td>" . $row[2] . "</td><td>
                  <a href='searchtable.php?lid=" . $row[0] . "'>Change</a></td><td>
                  <a href='managementdel.php?lid=" . $row[0] . "'>Delete</a></td></tr>";

      }

      echo "</table>";

?>
```

**managementdel.php**

```
<?php

$ac = $_GET['lid'];

 $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

  mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

  $sql = "delete from loginacc where LoginID = '$ac'";   




  if(mysql_query($sql))

  {
               echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=management.php>';

        }
        else
        {
                echo 'fail!';
                echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=management.php>';
        }


echo mysql_error()
?>
```